# zlib fails to build if --zprefix is specified

Tags: build, zlib

env:
Linux/x86_64

```bash
./configure --zprefix
make
```

error message:

```
gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -c -o example64.o test/example.c
as: symbol lookup error: as: undefined symbol: deflate
Makefile:153: recipe for target 'example64.o' failed
make: *** [example64.o] Error 1
```

This problem occurs in both zlib 1.2.11 and zlib 1.2.12.

Comment: "Linux" could be a million different combinations of operating systems, environments, compilers, etc. I just tried `--zprefix` with zlib 1.2.12 on a system with Debian 4.9 and gcc 6.3.0, and it worked fine.

Comment: ```uname -a```show "Linux dggphisprd24174 4.15.0-163-generic #171-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 11:55:11 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

Comment: ```unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH``` before compilation. Then the compilation succeeds.

Comment: Write an answer to your own question.

Comment: Thank you for testing and answering @MarkAdler

Answer (score 1):

```bash
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./configure --zprefix
make
```